# Failed to extract x86_64

Tags: ios, flutter

I am getting this error when I run on iOS simulator

```
 BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
fatal error: lipo: -extract x86_64 specified but fat file: /build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/App does not contain that architecture
Failed to extract x86_64 for build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/App. Running lipo -info:
Architectures in the fat file: /build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/App are: armv7 arm64
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 7.
```

Also when I run the app on real device I get the below error.

```
 Could not install build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app on 
 Try launching Xcode and selecting "Product > Run" to fix the problem:
 open ios/Runner.xcworkspace
```

Comment: You need to open the project in Xcode and run from there for the first time for real device. Then you can use your IDE

Comment: @SelimKundakçıoğlu I have run using xcode as well. Previously everything was working well but suddenly this error is coming

Comment: @SelimKundakçıoğlu Any other solution for this?

Comment: could you please explain why should I do like this for more detail @SelimKundakçıoğlu

Comment: how did you solve this problem finally? did you find the reason? @USER9561